# Ruby - Capitalize a title using map and capitalize methods

Tags: ruby, class, methods, getter-setter

I'm working through The Odin Projects Ruby basics and completely stuck on 05_book_titles. 
The title needs to be capitalized, including the 1st word but not including "small words" (ie "to", "the", etc) UNLESS it's the 1st word.
I can't get the code to do anything besides capitalize everything. Am I misusing map method? How can I get it to include the no_cap words in the returned title without capitalizing?

The Ruby file:

```
class Book
def title
    @title
end 

def title=(title)
    no_cap = ["if", "or", "in", "a", "and", "the", "of", "to"]
    p new_title = @title.split(" ")
    p new_new_title = new_title.map{|i| i.capitalize if !no_cap.include? i}
.join(" ") 
end
end
```

Some of the Spec file:

```
require 'book'

describe Book do

  before do
    @book = Book.new
  end

  describe 'title' do
    it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
      @book.title = "inferno"
      expect(@book.title).to eq("Inferno")
    end

    it 'should capitalize every word' do
      @book.title = "stuart little"
      expect(@book.title).to eq("Stuart Little")
    end

    describe 'should capitalize every word except...' do
      describe 'articles' do
        specify 'the' do
          @book.title = "alexander the great"
          expect(@book.title).to eq("Alexander the Great")
        end

        specify 'a' do
          @book.title = "to kill a mockingbird"
          expect(@book.title).to eq("To Kill a Mockingbird")
        end

        specify 'an' do
          @book.title = "to eat an apple a day"
          expect(@book.title).to eq("To Eat an Apple a Day")
        end
      end

      specify 'conjunctions' do
        @book.title = "war and peace"
        expect(@book.title).to eq("War and Peace")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Result:

```
Book
  title
    should capitalize the first letter (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Book title should capitalize the first letter
     Failure/Error: @book.title = "inferno"

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
     # ./05_book_titles/book.rb:8:in `title='
     # ./05_book_titles/book_titles_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.0015 seconds (files took 0.28653 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./05_book_titles/book_titles_spec.rb:24 # Book title should capitalize the first letter
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@title` before it's assigned in

```
new_title = @title.split(" ")
```

It should be changed to `title`.

You don't assign the calculated title to `@title` at the end of the `title=` method.

You also need to add 'an' to `no_cap` in order to pass the spec using "to eat an apple a day" as title.

And take care of the first word:

```
class Book
  def title
      @title
  end 

  def title=(title)
      no_cap = ["if", "or", "in", "a", "and", 'an', "the", "of", "to"]
      new_title = title.split(' ').each_with_index.map do |x, i|
          unless i != 0 && no_cap.include?(x)
            x.capitalize
          else
            x
          end
      end

      @title = new_title.join(' ')
  end
end
```

Comment: Note: `"My dog has ______fleas.".split(' ').join(' ') #=> "My dog has fleas."`, where the underscores represent extra spaces (which, if they were spaces, would be removed by SO).

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, but I don't know if that would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`small_words = [`<sub><sup><sub><sup>"if", "or", "in", "a", "and", "the", "of", "to"</sup></sub></sup></sub>`]`

```
str = "tO be      Or Not to be."
```

```
str.gsub(/\p{Alpha}+/) { |s| Regexp.last_match.begin(0) > 0 &&
  small_words.include?(s.downcase) ? s.downcase : s.capitalize }
  #=> "To Be      or Not to Be."
```

Comment: those are very very `small_words` by the way !

Comment: According to AP style, the list of words that are not capitalized in titles is *a, an, and, at, but, by, for, in, nor, of, on, or, out, so, the, to, up* and *yet*. (*If* isn't one of them.) Also, *at, by, for, in, of, out, so, to, up* and *yet* are not capitalized when used as prepositions, but capitalized when used as adverbs, e.g. *Joe Pulls the Door To*, *Clemson Has Yet to Lose*, *Jill Looks Up a Friend*, etc. So, the solution is more complicated than this unless the OP is simplifying the rules, in which case he might need to state his rules more clearly.

Comment: @Bob, hmmm. More than a minor tweak to determine if a small word is being used as an adverb, but I doubt that's the goal of the exercise. I expect many readers would hard pressed to explain what an adverb is. I learned that in the 6th grade, by diagramming sentences.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I doubt it too, because it's certainly non-trivial and rather an edge case of the problem of "correctly" capitalizing titles. But I thought it was worth mentioning, since we humans have a way of believing we have solved a broader problem than we have actually solved when solving a subset of a problem.